# Как получить данные от датчика из API ChirpStack?

Tags: python, api

Всем привет. Я полностью развернул сервер, сейчас потаюсь понять как мне получить данные от датчика с помощью api. Пишу на python. Сгенерировал сокет, только как дальше не пойму. Есть метод GET /api/devices/{dev_eui}, только там нет поля data
Буду благодарен за любую помощь.